# If a subspace $(A, T_A)$ of a space $(X,T)$ is connected, then $A ∩ A' ≠ ∅$.

Tags: general-topology

I start by assuming that $A \cap A' = \emptyset$, then if $x$ is in $A$, we have that $x$ is not in $A'$.  Then there exists an open set $U$ of $T$ such that $A ∩ U = \{x\}$, but from there I can't find a way to relate the connectedness to this limit point.

Comment: What is $A'$? What is $T_A$?

Comment: A' is the set of limit points of A and T_A is the subspace induced on A by T.

Comment: I think I'm missing something; what if $A=\left\{a\right\}$ is a singelton? Obviously it is connected, yet $A'=\varnothing$...

Comment: As Guy's comment indicates, one must assume that $A$ contains more than one point, otherwise it's wrong. (Although $\{a\}'$ can be nonempty if $T$ is not $T_1$, but in any case $\{a\}' \cap \{a\} = \varnothing$.)

Comment: When $A$ contains more than one point, and $A' \cap A = \varnothing$, then you need that for every $x\in A$ there is an open $U_x$ with $U_x \cap A = \{x\}$. Use that to deduce that $A$ is not connected.

Comment: The previous comment implies that if $A' \cap A = \varnothing$ then the induced topology on $A$ is the discrete topology, hence if $A$ has at least two points then it is not connected. When $X$ (or at least $A$) is T$_1$ and $A$ is connected then something stronger holds: $A\subseteq A'$, that is, $A' \cap A = A$.

Answer (score 0):

The corrected version of the statement:

Let $(A, \mathcal{T}_A)$ be a subspace of the space $(X,\mathcal{T})$, where $\mathcal{T}_A$ is the subspace topology of $A$ w.r.t. $\mathcal{T}$, and $A$ has at least two points. Then if $A$ is connected then $A' \cap A \neq \emptyset$.

The condition on the size of $A$ is necessary as taking $A$ as the empty set or any singleton in a $T_1$ space, makes $A$ connected but $A' = \emptyset$.

Suppose that $A' \cap A = \emptyset$. This means that for all $x \in A$, $x$ is not a limit point of $A$, so there exists an open set $U_x$ (containing $x$) such that $A \cap U_x = \{x\}$.

This means that all sets of the form $\{a\}$ for $a \in A$ are in $\mathcal{T}_A$ by definition. So $A$ has the discrete topology (all subsets of $A$ are open as unions of their singletons) and is thus disconnected: for any $a \in A$, $\{a\}$ and $A \setminus \{a\}$ are both open (in $A$), non-empty (as $A$ has size at least 2) and cover $A$.

If $X$ is $T_1$ as well, so singletons sets are closed, then we can even say more: $A \subseteq A'$ if $A$ is connected. For if *some* $a_0 \in A$ is not a limit point of $A$, then we have $U_{a_0}$ as before, so $\{a_0\}$ is open, but in a $T_1$ space it is also closed, so $\{a_0\}, A \setminus \{a_0\}$ again works as a disconnection of $A$. In that case we also have that $A' = \overline{A}$ is also connected.